# Is there a way to treat React components as strings?

Tags: reactjs, string, typescript

I'm working on a React with TypeScript application. I'm using a necessary library that has a component that takes a text property and renders it as an SVG. We'll call this library component `<LibraryRenderer />`.

I've wrapped this component in another component, `<Renderer />`, that passes the children (as text) into the library component like so:

```js
function Renderer(props: { children: string }) {
  return <LibraryRenderer text={props.children} />;
}
```

Now, what I'd like is to create a component that transforms the text inside of it into another string and use in the `<Renderer />` component. For instance, this new component `<Wrap />` could surround existing text with `"BEGIN"` and `"END"` respectively. Here's something like what I'd want the code to look like:

```js
function Wrap(props: { children: string }) {
  return `BEGIN ${props.children} END`; 
}
```

Then, you'd be able to use these components in a hierarchy like this:

```js
<Renderer>
  <Wrap>
    <Wrap>
      Some Inner Text
    </Wrap>
  </Wrap>
</Renderer>
```

And I would want this to reduce to:

```js
<LibraryRenderer text={"BEGIN BEGIN Some Inner Text END END"} />
```

I could write the text-transformation components as regular ol' functions but it seems like that would remove some of the nice flexibility of JSX syntax. Also, if I ever had props or state inside any of these text-transformation components, I wouldn't be able to use React to manage them.

```
function Wrap(value: string) {
  return `BEGIN ${props.children} END`;
}

<Renderer>
  {Wrap(
    Wrap(
      "Some Inner Text"
    )
  )}
</Renderer>
```

I feel like this might not exactly be the correct usage of React but I think that depends on if its possible and whether the code is "hacky" or not. Any help for how I should move forward would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think using JSX to generate your wrapped text is possible and not hacky. Please have a look at the following [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-waterfall-j3vmc?file=/src/App.tsx). If that's working for you, I can add an answer to explain the code.

Comment: @AWolf, your demo works for if `LibraryRenderer` were to take Elements as `text`. But, in my case, `LibraryRenderer` must strictly take `string` values only.

Comment: OK, I've updated the code. Now, a new prop called `input` is used to generate the `text` prop which is a `string` value.

Comment: @AWolf, okay. I can adapt your demo to work for my purposes. Feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to generate the text with a `Wrap` component.

The markup in your app render method will be like following:

```
return (
    <Renderer>
        <Wrap>
          <Wrap>Hello world</Wrap>
        </Wrap>
    </Renderer>
);
```

This will generate the text `BEGIN BEGIN Hello world END END` inside of the `Renderer` component.

For the `Wrap` component we're using a `span`-tag to wrap our text with the following code:

```
const Wrap: FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {
  return <span style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>BEGIN {children} END</span>;
};
```

The `Renderer` component is getting the text with components as children with the following code (`LibrarayRenderer` will be explained later):

```
const Renderer: FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {
  const [finalText, setText] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <LibraryRenderer text={finalText} input={children} setText={setText} />
      <p>Generated text: {finalText}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can see, we're creating a state variable `finalText` for our text that will be generated by our `LibraryRenderer` component.
The `input` prop are the children with the wrapped text and `setText` is passed so we can update the `finalText` inside of the renderer.
The `finalText` is also passed to the `LibraryRender` as this is needed there later (**Note:** It will be available on the second render because at the first render it's not ready.)

### How to create the text with JSX markup?

Now, we're ready to generate the `LibraryRenderer` that will create the text for us.

```
type LibraryRendererProps = {
  text: string;
  input: ReactNode;
  setText: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
};

const LibraryRenderer: FunctionComponent<LibraryRendererProps> = ({
  text,
  input,
  setText
}) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setText(ref?.current?.innerText || "");
  }, [ref, setText]);

  console.log("text", text); // needed for renderer as string
  // hiding the h1 with css because we're just using it to generate the text
  return (
    <h1 ref={ref} style={{ display: "none" }}>
      {input}
    </h1>
  );
};
```

We're returning a heading (any other inline element will work) with `display: "none"` style and a reference. The CSS is just used so it won't be displayed in the DOM. The reference is needed to get the text later. The `{input}` will render our children with the wrapped text.

Now, we have to do a `useEffect` with the `ref` as array parameter - so this `useEffect` will run if the reference changes. Inside of it, we're setting the `finalText` to the `innerText` of our rendered HTML by using our `setText` method.
The HTML in DOM looks like:

```html
<h1 style="display: none;">
  <span style="border: 1px solid red;">BEGIN <span style="border: 1px solid red;">BEGIN Hello world END</span> END</span>
</h1>
```

With `innerText` we're getting every text inside the `h1`-tag. The border style on the `span` is just for debugging (if `display: none` is removed).
So we're now having the text `BEGIN BEGIN Hello world END END`.

### Typing

I've used [FunctionComponent](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L540) for the type of our components, so `children` prop is defined there. You may have seen `SFC` type in other examples but this is deprecated because React function components are no longer considered stateless - use `FunctionComponent` instead.

If you'd like to add more types you can add them to the `FunctionComponent` as a generic type like in the above snippet with `FunctionComponent<LibraryRendererProps>`

The `LibraryRendererProps` type:

- `input: ReactNode;` same typing as children types
- `text: string;` our generated text as `string`
- `setText: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;` uses `React.Dispatch` and `SetStateAction` type with `setState` type as string

## Demo

You can find the complete code below (with-out typing) or in the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-waterfall-j3vmc) with Typescript.

```js
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

const LibraryRenderer = ({ text, input, setText }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setText(ref.current.innerText || "");
  }, [ref, setText]);

  console.log("text", text); // needed for renderer as string
  // hiding the h1 with css because we're just using it to generate the text
  return (
    <h1
      ref={ref}
      style={{
        display: "none",
      }}
    >{input}
    </h1>
  );
};

const Renderer = ({ children }) => {
  const [finalText, setText] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <LibraryRenderer text={finalText} input={children} setText={setText} />
      <p>Generated text: {finalText}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Wrap = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <span
      style={{
        border: "1px solid red",
      }}
    > BEGIN {children} END 
    </span>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Renderer>
        <Wrap>
          <Wrap>Hello world</Wrap>
        </Wrap>
      </Renderer>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

React is used to build the UI, but in your case you are operating on string, so using pure functions totally make sense.

In the last example, I will do something like

```
const generatedText = wrap(wrap("Some Inner Text"))
return <Renderer>{generatedText}</Renderer>
```